# Clicar em elementos abaixo de uma div?

Tags: html, css

Um exemplo que posso dar:

```css
.noturno{
  z-index: 9000; 
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="noturno">
</div>

<div class="corpo">
  <button>Teste</button>
  <a href="#">Teste 1</a>
</div>
```

Queria saber como torno a `div.noturno` "transparente" para cliques, ou seja, podendo clicar no botão, link, etc abaixo dela?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adicione no css da classe noturno:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: +1, não conhecia.

Answer (score 1):

A sua `div.noturno` tem praticamente o mesmo CSS da div de esmaecimento do `modal` do `jQueryUI`, e a intenção dela é justamente impedir a interação do usuario com os demais elementos da pagina.

Neste caso, o dialogo em si só fica acessivel, pois ele tem um z-index maior que a div `modal` ou está dentro da `div.noturno`.

z-index maior

```css
.noturno{
  z-index: 9000; 
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.corpo{
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 9001; 
}
```

```html
<div class="noturno">
</div>

<div class="corpo">
  <button>Teste</button>
  <a href="#">Teste 1</a>
</div>
```

div interna:

```css
.noturno{
  z-index: 9000; 
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="noturno">
  <div class="corpo">
    <button>Teste</button>
    <a href="#">Teste 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Só que daí no caso fugia do meu propósito, que era fazer um "modo noturno" deixar o site todo mais escuro.. A outras resposta deu certo.